# Copy Specific Sheet Name to Another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a sheet from multiple documents into a single document. The sheet name will always be the same and the main workbook being copied to will have a query to run through the links of each document to copy the specific sheet name to.

When running I get an subscript out of range once it opens the documents to copy from.

```
Sub GetIndex()
 Dim wb as Workbook
 For Each Cell in Selection
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Cell.Value)
   Sheets("Name of sheet").Copy Before:=Workbooks("Link to main document").Sheets("Sheet1")
  wb.Save
  wb.Close
 Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Your error means that either the sheet name or the workbook does not exist. More likely that the name does not exactly match. I've had this happen occasionally, so you should put some error handling code around it and flag the problem sheet/workbook for inspection.

Comment: You should use `wb.Sheets("Name of sheet").Copy`  - best to be explicit about the workbook you're copying from.  Plus if you're copying from ore than one file you can't have two sheets with the same name in the destination workbook.